# Error al consumir web service c#

Tags: c#, webservice

Buenas, 
al consumir un servicio web publico en `C#` obtengo este mensaje.
A que puede ser debido?

El tipo de contenido `text/html` del mensaje de respuesta no coincide con el tipo de contenido del enlace `text/xml; charset=utf-8`. Si usa un codificador personalizado, asegúrese de que el método `IsContentTypeSupported` se implemente correctamente.

Los primeros 1024 bytes de la respuesta fueron:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
   <title>Agencia Tributaria - Se ha producido un error</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">       
<link href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/css/xzhtcs04.css" orel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggle()
{
   var o=document.getElementById("AEAT_errores_tecnicos");
   o.style.display=(o.style.display=='' || .style.display=='none')?'block':'none';
}
```

---

Este es mi código, ¿puede ser no esté bien añadido el certificado?

```
 X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My,
  StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    LRConsultaEmitidasType ddd = new LRConsultaEmitidasType();
    SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas iverview = new   SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas();
    // sca.ClientCertificates.Add(store.Certificates[3]);

    sca.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "1234567890");

    //sca.(principal);
    try
    {
        sca.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(principal);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 

    }
```

Comment: Una causa de esto puede ser que el servicio que estés consumiendo no sea el mismo que agregaste a la solución o que el servicio no esté actualizado.

Comment: Es un servicio de Hacienda Española, no creo que haya cambiado....

Comment: Entonces revisa que la dirección del endpoint sea correcta y siempre sería bueno que preguntaras sí hubo algún cambio.

Comment: EndPoint     https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP  no parece q haya cambios, esta actualizado.

Comment: El Web service requiere de certificado, creo que esta indicado pero no termina de funcionar.

Comment: Hola. La comunicación se realiza sobre https? Si es asi necesitas entonces un certificado reconocido y admitido por la AEAT instalado en el equipo donde se realiza la comunicación.

Comment: Proba con la aplicación SoapUI para ver si el WebService esta funcionando correctamente

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que el servicio que invocas esta generando un error interno devolviendo el html de la pagina de error de asp.net

- Si el servicio que invocas es propio, podrias poner un breakpoint y
  evaluar cual es el error que se esta generando.
- Si es un error en produccion, podrias en el codigo definir un bloque
  `try...catch` que abarque todo el servicio, de esta forma cuando
  falle puedas capturarlo y retornar el mensaje del exception como xml 
  para que no afecte el formado esperado por el cliente y puedas
  procesar el mensaje de error. Mejor aun si puedes en el servidor loguear el problema para tener un mayor detalle del problema.

Esta claro que el problema es un error no controlado dentro del servicio, entonces asp.net retorna la pagina por defecto con la descripcion del problema. 
Tu cliente no esta preparado para recibir este html y procesarlo, ya que solo entiende el xml con los datos de respuesta